# Permissions group dialout don't apply

Tags: permissions, serial-port, groups

I'm using an application that needs to communicate through a usb-serial cable, using /dev/ttyUSB0.

Both /dev/ttyUSB0 and the user who owns the process are in group dialout, and the rights on the port are set correctly (as far as I can see).

However, my application works only if I change the permissions of the port:
`sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0`. I don't want to do that manually every time.

The application is Node-RED. I use it to exchange data with a Mitsubishi PLC (not an Arduino). `getent group dialout` does show the right user.

Other things I have tried:
After a reboot the communication does not resume automatically.
Powercycling the PLC does not help. However, when I restart the Node-RED process (`node-red-restart`), the communication is magically restored. I suspected the first node-red process might have had a different owner but that is not the case, I checked.

I'm no longer sure it's a permissions problem, but there is still a problem ...

```
$ /bin/ls -l $( type -p node-red )
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 35 aug 17 15:09 /usr/bin/node-red -> ../lib/node_modules/node-red/red.js
$ id
uid=1000(jw) gid=1000(jw) groups=1000(jw),4(adm),20(dialout),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),4120(lpadmin),130(lxd),131(sambashare)
$ getent group dialout
dialout:x:20:jw
$ ls -la /dev/ttyUSB0
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 sep 26 15:17 /dev/ttyUSB0
$ ps aux | grep node-red
jw          1383 10.1  6.2 896816 62012 ?        RNsl sep25   6:02 node-red
jw          2154  0.0  0.2   9040  2492 pts/0    S+   00:51   0:00 grep --color=auto node-red
```

Comment: What's your application? Is it setuid/setgid? Does `getent group dialout` show the user?

Comment: Please edit your post to add new information, properly formatted. Information added via comments is hard for you to format, hard for us to read, ignored by AskUbuntu's indexing system, and ignored by future readers. Please click [edit] and add that vital information to your question so all the facts we need are in the question. Please don't use Add Comment, since that's our uplink to you. All facts about your system should go in the Question with [edit]

Comment: Please edit your question and show `/bin/ls -l $( type -p Node-RED )` to see if it's setuid/setgid. Use `id` to see the current process's group membership. Use `sudo adduser $USER dialout` to  add `$USER` to the `dialout` group, and either log out/in or `newgrp dialout`. `man id adduser newgrp`.

Answer (score 0):

you are using an arduino, or some device like that I assume. Likely, you need your user to have dialout permission, rather than your device. give your user permission with this command `sudo usermod -a -G dialout $USER`

you might also want to know about the [arduino stackexchange](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: It's a Mitsubishi Alpha-2, not an Arduino.

Comment: its an MCU, the arduino stackexchange covers more than 1 brand specific topic. you might also need to write some udev rules.

Answer (score 0):

Because I wasn't sure whether this was a Linux problem or a Node-RED problem I asked the same question on their forum.
My issue turns out to be solved if I delay the node-red start for a bit on boot.

For a description follow [link](https://discourse.nodered.org/t/serial-communication-problem/33407)